# How to send data from list into form with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a List of elements and a Form (for creating/changing elements). With react I represent it as following

```
...
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <List/>
            <Form/>
        </div>
    )
}
...
```

Each list element has a change button. Clicking on it, fetch element field values. How I can fill form fields with element values (without Redux)?

Comment: is this really working.? You return statement is wrong.

Comment: @Ved Thanks, update a code section. Can you help me with question?

Comment: Post your complete code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to manage the state in the parent component :

1) change the state when a list element is clicked
2) transmit the state element to the form component by adding a property

```
...
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {}
    this.fillForm = this.fillForm.bind(this);
}


fillForm(element) {
   this.setState({
      element: element
   });
}


render() {
   return (
       <div>
         <List onElementClick={this.fillForm} />
         <Form element={this.state.element}/>
       </div>
   )
}
...
```

In the **List** component, when a element is clicked you have to call this function `this.props.onElementClick(elementClicked)`

In the **Form** component you can get the element fields with this property `this.props.element`

Comment: Ok, I think in the same way too:) But this is looks like Redux approach.

Comment: As I understand, there is no another way:
- using state of parent component
- using Redux
- ?

Comment: this is not redux, redux provide a single store with reducers, in this solution there is just a parent-child communication by properties

Comment: @Evgeniy I don't know better way than Parent-Child or Redux

Answer (score 0):

It is not what you asked. I am Just correcting your mistake.

```
render() {//wrong
    return (
        <List/>
        <Form/>
    )
}
```

You can't return multiple componenets. You need to wrap all components inside a  element.
ex:

```
render() {
    return (
<div>
        <List/>
        <Form/>
</div>
    )
}
```

Edit: to fill form fields with element data, you need pass  component data as props.

```
<Form data={this.state.data}/>
```